# Input vertical align

Tags: input, alignment, textarea

I have a specific problem. I have an

`<input type="text">`

with css style

`input{height:2500px;}`

when I open it in browser, and click on the text area, I will type at the middle of the inputs height. I want to type right from the left top corner, How do I do this? help me please ...

Comment: Have you referred to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050460/html-textarea-cursor-starting-in-center-of-textarea-rather-than-top) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15382422/text-doesnt-start-from-the-left-top-of-input-text-field) ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set your text-align to left and remove padding from top and left sides:

```
textarea{
   text-align: left;
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

**UPD**:

Well I don't quite get if you need an input or a textarea... If you have an `<input>`, this one will not work, cause `<input>` is intended to display only single-row info. So, for `<input>` just set it's height similar to the font height.